# Add value from text boxes to result text box when user checks off the checkbox beside the appropriate text box

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

I'm trying to add the values from text boxes to the results text box when the user checks off the appropriate checkbox beside each text box but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<form>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="value" value="10">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="value" value="20">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="value" value="30">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="value" value="40">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="value" value="50">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
</div>

<div id="result"><input class="final" type="text" value=""></div>
</form>
```

This is my jquery so far for adding the text box values to the result text box... I've tried many variations and I know this is wrong, any help would be awesome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.final').val($(this).siblings($('.value')).val());
        } else {
            $('.final').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: do you mean add all the values and put the sum into the final text field? if so it can be simply like this http://jsfiddle.net/2b7VZ/2/

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check').change(function() {
        if($('.check:checked').length > 0) {
            $('.final').val( $('.check:checked').prev().map(function(v,i){
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',') );
        } else {
            $('.final').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/LbpfB/)

If by add you meant find the sum of all the values you could use `.sum()` as defined below instead of `.join()`:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    var xx = 0;
    for(i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        xx += +this[i];
    }
    return xx;
};
```

Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/LbpfB/1/)